# Flutter Map: .shp, .dbf, etc

Tags: flutter, parsing, maps, geojson

I have several areas as shape files.

What are the steps to show this areas with flutter maps?

Do I have to parse it to geojson? How?

Flutter maps does need LatLng I think. Can I parse it to something like that?

Do not find any solutions yet...

Answer (score 0):

Donno much about the maps domain but found an external source. Maybe helpful. If not sry!

[https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12367/how-to-visualize-the-shp-files-in-flutter-maps#:~:text=Step%202%3A%20Drop%20the%20shape,be%20seen%20on%20the%20screen](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12367/how-to-visualize-the-shp-files-in-flutter-maps#:%7E:text=Step%202%3A%20Drop%20the%20shape,be%20seen%20on%20the%20screen).

Comment: I found that, but the pricing is too heavy: https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products ...

Comment: same problem facing